# Python function containing sql request for openerp

Tags: python, openerp-7

I have a field which is a result of a function (`fields.function`). But my function contains an SQL request and I don't understand how to create it.

Here is what i have tried:

**Function:**

```
   def _total_get(self, cr, uid, context=None):

    cr.execute('select total from hr_payslip_line where code = "22001"')

  return cr.fetchall()
```

**Field:**

```
   'a':fields.function(_total_get, type = 'float',store=False,method=True,obj="HrPayslip",string="L"),
```

**Error:**
    TypeError: _total_get() takes at most 4 arguments (7 given)

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
def _total_get(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names=None, arg=False, context=None):

    cr.execute('select total from hr_payslip_line where code = "22001"')

    return cr.fetchall()
```

Function takes 7 arguments default.

Answer (score 0):

**Signature for function field is:**

```
def _total_get(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
```

**Available Parameter:**

```
function(fnct, arg=None, fnct_inv=None, fnct_inv_arg=None, type='float',fnct_search=None, obj=None, store=False, multi=False,...)
```

**Your function:**

```
def _total_get(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    cr.execute('select total from hr_payslip_line where code = "22001"')
    total = cr.fetchone();
    total = total and total[0] or 0.0
    return dict.fromkeys(ids, total)
```

Note: Function field return type is dictionary.